# How to pass data from Silverlight OOB application to asp.net website?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-oob, out-of-browser

I created silver-light 4.0 application in that user can enter their username and password. 
After submit this secret data(username, password ) from SL application,
it submitted to website with query string..
I want to pass as below URL string
for ex:  -  
**http://testsite.com/mypage.aspx?<encrypted string>**

I want to pass username and password in encrypted format from SL to Aspx page..
How I pass those information from SL application to asp.net website..

Comment: Is it your own web page that the credentials are being submitted to? If so, what does the web page give you? Why don't you use a WCF service instead? Or are you submitting to a third party web site (in which case they should already have a spec on how you should do it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you could just use the [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) class and GET the page.

(I'm assuming your doing asp.net WebForms NOT MVC)

Your asp.net page should be a blank page, in your code behind you read your query string and do what you need with it, depending on success or failure you write the appropriate response with `Response.Write();`.

In your silverlight code, you will just need to request for your page, and you can then read the response from your asp.net page.

**Asp.net:**

```
var encyString = Request.QueryString["str"];
//some logic
Response.Write("Success");
```

**Silverlight:**

```
WebClient client = new WebClient(); 
client.DownloadStringCompleted +=
    new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(
    client_DownloadStringCompleted);
```

In `Button1_Click`, I call [DownloadStringAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144202%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), passing the complete URL that includes the number specified by the user.

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string encryptedString = "example";
    client.DownloadStringAsync
      (new Uri("http://testsite.com/mypage.aspx?"+encryptedString));
}
```

In the DownloadStringCompleted event-handler, I check that the Error property of the event args is null, and either output the response or the error message to the text block.

```
void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender,
  DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
        resultBlock.Text = "Using WebClient: "+  e.Result;
        //will be Response.Write();

    else
        resultBlock.Text = e.Error.Message;
}
```

Above code was plagiarized from [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2008/04/01/using-webclient-and-httpwebrequest.aspx).

Remember, a sniffer can read your request. You may want to use SSL if you need better security. Possibly a more secure way to send this data would be to POST it to your asp.net page.

[This article](http://viswaug.wordpress.com/2009/09/17/making-a-http-post-in-silverlight-a-k-a-thread-hopping/) describes how to POST from silverlight to a page.

HTH

Comment: Hello @giddy Is it possible in SL OOB application which runs from client PC to website page.. I passed parameter as a query string from Out of browser application to default.aspx page.. ?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, you can request from a OOB SL app if this app was installed from the same domain. (Ex: the App was installed from testapp.com) If it was installed from another domain, then you will have to include a *clientaccesspolicy.xml* file on the root of testapp.com so your SL app can access it. [See this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032(v=vs.95).aspx) There are numerous default examples of _clientaccesspolicy.xml_ you can find if you google it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for good suggestion. My application runs Out of browser (on client machine ) then I enter user-name and password into application and passes with query string in encrypted format like this url: http://www.testsite.com/mypage.aspx?<encrypted_string>

Answer (score 1):

What I understood from the question is that you are authenticating user twice – First in SL app and then in ASP.Net app. Instead can you just authenticate user in SL and pass the result (True/False or token may be) to ASP.Net app? This is the safe way I feel.

Comment: So How to communicate with SQL server and check Is it authorized or not.

Comment: I not authenticate user twice. just I check user authenticate from page only.. I not know how to authenticate user from SL with sql server.

Comment: See this video -  [link](http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/all/use-aspnet-authentication-silverlight-3/). It is for SL3 but should work for SL4. What you are looking for is complex, so you need to understand authentication process well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like HtmlPage.Window.Eval("window.location.href='"+ YOURURL +"'");

Comment: @Priyan_R I want to pass username and password from SL application to new webpage with encrypted query string to url

Comment: Pass the Url Querystring encrypted from silverlight using cryptography checkout http://scrypt.codeplex.com/